# The element to find the link does not work instead browser.driver.findElement works

Tags: protractor

The login page of my app is not built with angular, but after the login, the pages that its lands and remaining app is built with angularjs.

To get the url I used `browser.driver.get('//appurl');` which works fine.

After the login, `element(by.css('a[href="#!/test"]')).click();` does not work, where as `browser.driver.findElement(by.css('a[href="#!/test"]')).click();` worked !!

Below is the error

> ScriptTimeoutError: script timeout: result was not received in 11
>   seconds
>         (Session info: chrome...
>         (Driver info: ...,...)
>           at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
>           at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
>           at doSend.then.response (C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30)
>           at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
>       From: Task: Protractor.waitForAngular() - Locator: By(css selector, a[href="#!/workpieces"])
>           at thenableWebDriverProxy.schedule (C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:807:17)
>           at ProtractorBrowser.executeAsyncScript_ (C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\browser.js:425:28)
>           at angularAppRoot.then (C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\browser.js:456:33)
>   at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_
>   (C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1376:14)
>           at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3084:14)
>           at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3067:27)
>           at asyncRun (C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2927:27)
>           at C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:668:7
>           at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)Error
>           at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:459:27)
>           at ElementArrayFinder.(anonymous function).args [as click] (C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:91:29)
>           at ElementFinder.(anonymous function).args [as click] (C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:831:22)
>           at UserContext. (C:\Users\testuser\repos\test\spec.js:21:53)
>           at C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:112:25
>           at new ManagedPromise (C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1077:7)
>           at ControlFlow.promise (C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2505:12)
>           at schedulerExecute (C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:95:18)
>           at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3084:14)
>           at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3067:27)
>       From: Task: Run it("Test") in control flow
>           at UserContext. (C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:94:19)
>       From asynchronous test:
>       Error
>           at Suite. (C:\Users\testuser\repos\test\spec.js:20:5)
>           at Object. (C:\Users\testuser\repos\test\spec.js:1:63)
>           at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
>           at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
>           at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
>           at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)

Comment: could you share your error and your test script

Comment: Is this because you are going to a page that is not Angular? I agree that there should be more info here.

Comment: Its spa web application

Comment: Its a hybridapp angularJS + angular, let me know if more info should be added

Comment: i am having same issue wherein locally `element(by.css(` works but in Devops Release pipeline `browser.driver.findElement(by.css(` works to some extent but then  errors